# QuickSight line chart with two Y-axis dimensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight, tableau-desktop

I've been given the task of migrating a dashboard from Tableau to QuickSight and, probably since QuickSight is a bit less mature than Tableau, I've noticed some missing features.

In particular we have a 2D Y-axis graph in Tableau, i.e. we have dates as X-axis and some values in the Y-axis grouped by "machines" like the image below

[image]

Is it possible to replicate this behavior in QuickSight? If not, what would you think it'd be the closest approach in order to express the same information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In QuickSight, you can only group by in the same chart. So you would have multiple graphs (all representing the same metric) in the same chart where each graph corresponds to a different machine.
You would then have the same visual but for a different metric.

To get the exact same format as you have right now, you would need to add a visual for each machine.

Comment: I was afraid of reading this since the groups are dynamic. I guess we'll have to delete this feature from our dashboard, thanks for your answer!

Comment: Unless it's an option to display things differently as I mentioned in the first paragraph

Comment: I tried what you suggested in the first paragraph but there are just too many lines. The idea was to easily compare different measures (up to ~30) among different graphs (~40 on average) so having everything in one single graph would've been chaotic

Answer (score 1):

November 2022 update

---

You can now use the "Small multiples" feature to achieve that :
[Quicksight visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmF7y.png)
You can set it in the [field wells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdXsu.png)